# What is the difference between 'attest' and 'attest to'?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between 'attest' and 'attest to'? When should we use the phrase attest to and when should attest be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking for the difference between the transitive verb ("attest" or "attest that") and the intransitive verb ("attest to")

> I attest that this court transcript is complete and unaltered.

means "I promise (in a legally binding sense) that this court transcript ..."

> I can attest to his honesty and good character.

means "I have a substantial history of witnessing his honesty and good character."

See the two definitions of "[attest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attest)"

Transitive verb (definition 1)

> to affirm to be true or genuine; specifically to authenticate by signing as a witness
>   to authenticate officially

Intransitive verb

> to bear witness